# Java Swing GUI freezes - observer pattern

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, observer-pattern

For a program I am creating I have used the observer pattern, yet whilst my Observable sends data almost constantly, simulated with a loop here because the actual code is hooked up to a device and measures the data, my update(); method runs as it should but swing doesn't.

Swing only updates the JTextField AFTER the loop has finished, yet when I use System.out.println() it iterates nicely each update.

Observable code:

```
public void collectData()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        currRandom = (Math.random() * 10);
        for(Observer o : observers)
        {
            notify(o);
        }

    }
}
```

Observer (SWING) code:

```
public void update()
{
    jRecievedData.setText(jRecievedData.getText() + "\n" + Double.toString(PVC.pc.getCurr()));
    jlAverage.setText("Average: " + PVC.getAverage());
    jlMin.setText("Minimum: " + PVC.getMin());
    jlMax.setText("Maximum: "+ PVC.getMax());

    // setText updates slow
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I have the feeling this is going to be a threading problem , but I'm not sure and if it is, I still don't know how to do that with swing)

Comment: I assume notify calls update() method. Since update() method changes the  contents of textfield, make sure it is called in EDT ( Event Dispatch Thread).

Comment: It is running in the EDT, no success =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping through your observers explicitly, let `Observable` do it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

```
this.setChanged();
this.notifyObservers();
```

Also, verify that you are not blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). If so, consider using [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which greatly simplifies Swing threading.

Comment: Thank you, I have used SwingWorker and once I had figured out how to get that working with my pattern mess it worked like a charm!